# Prettify json in a streaming log

Tags: json, bash, logging, sed, jq

I am trying to prettify aws logs stream

log format:

```
2022-09-07T17:14:35.987000+00:00 2022/09/07/[$LATEST]58f517bs4ebcsae033sd953bs734224 {"cold_start":true,"function_memory_size":512,"function_request_id":"a2cfdd5d-4b0b-4cfa-97c2-4af9ba6a1056","level":"ERROR","message":"Unexpected","sampling_rate":1,"timestamp":"2022-09-07T17:14:35.987Z","xray_trace_id":"1-6318d178-0e96c13a1399a74b4f353edd","extra":"{\"error\":\"AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::\",\"stack\":\"AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::\"}"}
```

I want to change this to

```
2022-09-07T17:14:35.987000+00:00 2022/09/07/[$LATEST]58f51004277b4ebcae033d953b734224 {
  "cold_start": true,
  "function_memory_size": 512,
  "function_request_id": "a2cfdd5d-4b0b-4cfa-97c2-4af9ba6a1056",
  "level": "ERROR",
  "message": "Unexpected",
  "sampling_rate": 1,
  "timestamp": "2022-09-07T17:14:35.987Z",
  "xray_trace_id": "1-6318d178-0e96c13a1399a74b4f353edd",
  "extra": '{"error":"AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::","stack":"AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::"}',
}
```

I tried this

```
aws logs tail /aws/lambda/lambda-name | sed -u -e "s/\({.*}\)/$(echo \'\\1\' | jq)/"
```

but I am getting this error

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You'll have much more efficiency to have jq do the whole thing and avoid sed altogether. It's perfectly capable of taking textual input and extracting JSON from it -- and starting a new copy of jq for each line of your log file is ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you feed your log sample to:

```
jq -rR 'index("{") as $ix | .[0:$ix], ( .[$ix:]|fromjson)'
```

you will get the log stamp followed by a copy of the corresponding valid JSON.

Your subject line indicates you want to "prettify" the JSON rather than mangle it, so I'll assume you didn't intend the latter.

If you really want the initial '{' to appear with the log stamp, then assuming a bash or bash-like shell, you could pipe the above into:

```
    sed $'/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-/ {N; s/\\n{/{/; }'
```